# 2012 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators, election

The 2012 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://superuser.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

> Please also note: [July 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5149/july-2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat)

Answer (score 12):

**The Community has spoken. According to [the election page](https://superuser.com/election/2), the new moderators have been picked:**

[image: Daniel Beck]
[image: Oliver Salzburg]
[image: slhck]

Congrats Daniel Beck, Oliver Salzburg & slhck for being the newest elected Community Moderators!