# July 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary. I will be working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

***The Town Hall Chat took place on Wednesday the 18th at 19:00:00Z UTC / 3:00 PM EDT. - a digest can be found [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5227/july-2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest)***

---

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the primary phase.  This means that I am looking around July 16th-18th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, this post shall be edited with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=superuser.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: I apologise for not making the chat. An unavoidable work issue took precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I will not be able to attend this fully, as I will be at work during that time.  I'll be able to join and <strike>listen</strike> read in, but cannot give my full attention and respond right away.  I will wait til later that day and respond to any questions posed to the candidates.

## Good Luck All!